# File.Create from IIS locking the created File

Tags: asp.net, iis, io

I have an ASP.NET running in IIS 7.5 that creates files on the local file system and then attempts to delete after performing some logic in between creation and deletion. I'm running into a situation though where deletion is failing with a response such as "The process cannot access the file 'C:...\Uploads\c1fe593f-85de-4de1-b5d1-7239e1fc0648_Tulips.jpg' because it is being used by another process.'" The file appears to be locked by IIS and I can't delete it. Here's an example of the code for creating and deleteing:

```
// File.WriteAllBytes(path, rawData); // this seems to leave the file open!
using (var file = File.Create(path))
{
    file.Write(rawData, 0, rawData.Length);
    file.Close(); // should close when it goes out of scope, but just to be safe
}
```

Is there some special option I need to pass into File.Create? How do I get around this?

Comment: Turns out I'm dumb. I forgot to clean-up another resources that had a handle on it. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

`File.WriteAllBytes(path, rawData);` should work fine assuming the path parameter you are passing is unique and that you don't have concurrent requests one writing and other trying to read at the same time. To ensure this you could use a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) to synchronize the access if this situation could potentially occur. Also make sure that there are no other parts of the code that might leak the file handle.

Take a look at [SysInternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) which could allow you to know exactly where this file handle is leaked.